# Bootstrap Modal Not Woking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I Have a code that will get the data from database to a modal pop up via ajax/json i successfully get the data. but im not able to show my modal. heres my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript">  

//Start Update Function
function GetUserDetails(EmployeesID) {
    // Add User ID to the hidden field for furture usage
    $("#hidden_user_id").val(EmployeesID);
    $.post("ajax/readUserDetails.php", {
            EmployeesID: EmployeesID
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // PARSE json data
            var tblinfo = JSON.parse(data);
            // Assing existing values to the modal popup fields
            $("#update_first_name").val(tblinfo.firstname);
            $("#update_last_name").val(tblinfo.lastname);
            $("#update_basic_salary").val(tblinfo.basicsalary);
          }
    );
    // Show Modal
 $("#update_user_modal").modal("show");
}
//End Update Function

body{
  background-color:#e9ecef;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topd">
<h1>Welcome to HopesV2.0</h1>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light w3-teal" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        HR
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="first.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you want to exit?')">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<BR>
<!-- Start Body -->
<div class="jumbotron zbody">
  <h1>Basic Information</h1>
  <hr class="my-4">
<p class="lead">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<!-- Modal - Update User details -->
<div class="modal fade" id="updateusermodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_last_name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_basic_salary">Basic Salary</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_basic_salary" placeholder="Basic Salary" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateUserDetails()" >Save Changes</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- // Modal -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h4>Records:</h4>
<div class="records_content"></div>
</div>

</form>
  </p>
</div>
<!-- End Body -->  
</body>
</html>
```

heres my readuserdetails.php

```
<?php
// include Database connection file
include("myconnection.php");

// check request
if(isset($_POST['EmployeesID']) && isset($_POST['EmployeesID']) != "")
{
    // get User ID
    $EmployeesID = $_POST['EmployeesID'];

    // Get User Details
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblinfo WHERE EmployeesID = '$EmployeesID'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $response = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response = $row;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['message'] = "Data not found!";
    }
    // display JSON data
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response['status'] = 200;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request!";
}
```

and my code for populating the data into tables:

```
<?php
    // include Database connection file 
    include("myconnection.php");

    // Design initial table header 
    $data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>No.</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Basic Salary</th>
                            <th>Update</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblinfo";

    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }

    // if query results contains rows then featch those rows 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $number = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$number.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['basicsalary'].'</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['EmployeesID'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['EmployeesID'].')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>';
            $number++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // records now found 
        $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">Records not found!</td></tr>';
    }

    $data .= '</table>';

    echo $data;
?>
```

i try to show the data i fetch via alert(data) and its shows that i already fetch data from my database. i just dont get why the bootstrap modal is not showing. its like reloading the page only.

Comment: Did you debug your JavaScript (set a breakpoint on $("#update_user_modal") and tblinfo)? Provide a minimal example.

Comment: you try to open modal when filling table in modal, when pressing button in modal ))) your script has bad logic, correct it. Button to open modal should be outside of modal or you never can press it

Comment: I see modal with `id` `updateusermodal`. Where is the modal with `id` `update_user_modal` in your code?

Comment: @phani sorry for the cnfusion i already correct it but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Open your modal after the AJAX is completed and the content is appended in the modal, your id is incorrect, it should be `updateusermodal`

```
function (data, status) {
  // PARSE json data
  var tblinfo = JSON.parse(data);
  // Assing existing values to the modal popup fields
  $("#update_first_name").val(tblinfo.firstname);
  $("#update_last_name").val(tblinfo.lastname);
  $("#update_basic_salary").val(tblinfo.basicsalary);
  $("#updateusermodal").modal("show");
}
```

change your onclick event to `onclick="GetUserDetails(EmployeesID,event)"`

prevent the default click intro your function:

```
 function GetUserDetails(EmployeesID,event) {
    event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: that means your ajax isn't successful,any console errors?

Comment: no console errors. and tried to show if i fetch any data via alert(data) and it works fine.

Comment: i think my error is in my function ? but i cannot figure out where is it. because when i try to run my modal in a button only without the ajax part it works perfectly.

Comment: is your page refreshing after the ajax?

Comment: in my observation. yes it is.

Comment: still not working. when i change my code the ajax also fails

Comment: you sad that ajax works, now you say the ajax fails,is it working or is it failing?what errors do you have in the console if it's failing ?what does your xhr body look like?

Comment: can we go team viewer ? im a little confused right now .

Comment: what's team viewer?

Comment: why are you confused?

Comment: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/ this you can access pc and see my codes.

Comment: this team view doesn't come for smartphones, why are you confused?

Comment: <button onclick="GetUserDetails(EmployeesID,event)" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>

Comment: when i change the codes . the ajax does not return a data at all